# How to extract a particular words inside double quote in swift when the string is full of special character?

Tags: swift

From the given data i.e.  -

> session_id="8b55ed3af15dcf154aaaedd1bb667489"/ip_address="103.16.104.24"/last_activity="1460548532"

How i can extract the values of session_id, ip_address and last_activity. I have tried the below code but it only work for simple strings and when i assign the given data its shows error

```
var testString: String = "session_id="8b55ed3af15dcf154aaaedd1bb667489"/ip_address="103.16.104.24"/last_activity="1460548532""

var data: String = testString
let extractedStringData = data.componentsSeparatedByString("/")

var session_id: String = extractedStringData[0]
var ip_address: String? = extractedStringData[1]
var last_activity: String? = extractedStringData [2]
```

any suggestion will be helpful
thank you

Comment: What is the error message? Note that you need to escape double-quotes inside string literals: please see the section "Special Characters in String Literals" in [Strings and Characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html).

Comment: Never heard of double quotes referred to as inverted commas.

Comment: @Andrew Sir The given data comes from scanning the QRCode,Will i have to append additional special character to get the values .

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Consecutive statement on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: and when i add ';' as per Xcode suggestion then the error is - Expected a digit integer literal prefix

Comment: @AbdulKarim For your string literal in the code, you must escape the double-quotes. That is because it needs to be able to parse what you have typed into code, and double-quotes normally indicate the end of a string literal. For the data from the scan, you should not escape the double-quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably a more functional way to do this, but this works:

```
var testString: String = "session_id=\"8b55ed3af15dcf154aaaedd1bb667489\"/ip_address=\"103.16.104.24\"/last_activity=\"1460548532\""

let pairs: [String] = testString.characters.split("/").map(String.init)
var values = [String:String]()
pairs.forEach({
    let pair: [String] = $0.characters.split("=").map(String.init)
    values[pair[0]] = pair[1]
})

testString: String = "session_id=\"8b55ed3af15dcf154aaaedd1bb667489\"/ip_address=\"103.16.104.24\"/last_activity=\"1460548532\""
pairs: [String] = 3 values {
  [0] = "session_id=\"8b55ed3af15dcf154aaaedd1bb667489\""
  [1] = "ip_address=\"103.16.104.24\""
  [2] = "last_activity=\"1460548532\""
}
values: [String : String] = 3 key/value pairs {
  [0] = {
    key = "last_activity"
    value = "\"1460548532\""
  }
  [1] = {
    key = "session_id"
    value = "\"8b55ed3af15dcf154aaaedd1bb667489\""
  }
  [2] = {
    key = "ip_address"
    value = "\"103.16.104.24\""
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your rlp @christopher Sir but the problem is the given data is coming from scanning the QRCode

Comment: Will i have to append additional special character to get the values @Christopher Sir

Comment: FYI, rather than `testString.characters.split("/").map(String.init)` pattern, I might just do `testString.componentsSeparatedByString("/")`. Re a more functional approach, one could use `reduce`, but that would be a little inefficient. Your answer is good.